# ReadTheDocs fails to clone due to CAfile

Tags: gitlab, read-the-docs

I have a project that was being published with no issues to RTD and it is now giving me a clone error all the time. I don't know if it is something that could have changed in my environment on in theirs.

**Command git clone --no-single-branch --depth 50 https:// . failed: Cloning into '.'... fatal: unable to access 'https://': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none**

Anyone had this problem before or know how to address it?

Comment: Are you self-hosting GitLab or using the SaaS version? The SSL certificate seems to be the issue here in that RTD isn't trusting the SSL cert of the gitlab environment.

Comment: Are you using your own runners or the shared runners provided by GitLab?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a self hosted gitlab instance with gitlab runners deployed in my environment as well. It worked just fine for a long time and my IT team tells me that they have not changed anything and indeed their test show that SSL is up and running. I have tested to trigger a build both manually and via integration (with and without ssl enabled). Any other test I could do?

Answer (score 2):

This was a temporary issue that was fixed, more details can be found here https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/8555